# JPA Query over JOINED table

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, persistence

The goal for this is to search using a keyword and both tables should be selected or shown. Below is the sample query that works on my sql console.

`SELECT * FROM Week_Cycle w JOIN Day d ON d.week_Cycle_ID = w.id WHERE w.logged_By LIKE 'samplename' OR  d.user_ID LIKE 'samplename'`

I was able to select the data but when I converted it as NamedQuery on my domain and then run it on my application it throws an SQL exception which shown below:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.6.v20200131-b7c997804f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Borrow prepareStatement from pool failed

Here is the NamedQuery:

`SELECT w FROM WeekCycle w JOIN Day d ON d.weekCycle = w.id WHERE w.loggedBy LIKE :keyword OR  d.userId LIKE :keyword`

Here is the WeekCycle domain:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WEEK_CYCLE")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = WeekCycle.FIND_ALL_WEEK_CYCLES_BY_KEYWORD, query = "SELECT w FROM WeekCycle w JOIN Day d ON d.weekCycle = w.id WHERE w.loggedBy LIKE :keyword OR  d.userId LIKE :keyword")})
public class WeekCycle{

    public static final String FIND_ALL_WEEK_CYCLES_BY_KEYWORD = "FindAllWeekCyclesByKeyword";


    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_WEEK_CYCLE", sequenceName = "SEQ_WEEK_CYCLE", allocationSize = 50, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_WEEK_CYCLE")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 255)
    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STATUS", length = 40)
    private WeekCycleStatus weekCycleStatus;

    @Column(name = "LOGGED_BY", length = 128)
    private String loggedBy;

    @OrderBy("id ASC")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "weekCycle", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Day> days = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here is the Day domain:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DAY")
public class Day {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_Day", sequenceName = "SEQ_Day", allocationSize = 50, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_Day")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = true)
    private String userId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "START_TIME")
    private LocalDateTime startTime;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DATA_SOURCE", nullable = true)
    private String dataSource;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "WEEK_CYCLE_ID")
    private WeekCycle weekCycle;
```

DAO:

```
public List<WeekCycle> searchOnWeekCycles(String keyword) {

        TypedQuery<WeekCycle> query = createEntityManager()
            .createNamedQuery(WeekCycle.FIND_ALL_WEEK_CYCLES_BY_KEYWORD, WeekCycle.class);
        query.setParameter("keyword", "%" + keyword + "%");

        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

Is there a criteria query equivalent with the namedQuery above??

Comment: It's likely that DAY is a reserved keyword, try to refactor-rename the class both in the db and Entity definition

Comment: Moreover it's not necessary to explicitly refer the join relation in the `where` condition

Comment: Yep, i already renamed “DAY”. What is the best approach in here? I need the where condition to search or select a specific data